# How to Set hessian's property" isOverloadEnabled = true "In Dubbo

Tags: overriding, hessian

Thanks in advance. 
I try to use the "dubbo" to invoke a method which is override.But the console tell me that "Caused by: com.caucho.hessian.io.HessianProtocolException: '' is an unknown code".
Search Engines told me that error may cased by "hessian" is not support override method default.So i try to set this property ,"isOverloadEnabled".But i can not find the way to set. I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

That's xml content :

```
<dubbo:protocol name="hessian" port="30002" threads="200" />

<dubbo:service ref="ossServiceImpl" interface="com.fragment.dede.apis.OssService" protocol="hessian"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

the hessian's version is 4.0.7  ,the dubbo's version is 2.5.3 ,JDK1.8 and SPRING4

Answer (score 0):

You have to use HessianProxyFactory. Then call:

```
factory.setOverloadEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
please say something useful
```

```xml
    <dubbo:protocol name="hessian" port="${dubbo.protocols.hessian.port:20882}">
        <dubbo:parameter key="timeout" value="10000000"/>
        <dubbo:parameter key="hessian.overload.method" value="true"/>
    </dubbo:protocol>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).